# URL rewrite of independent plugin?

Tags: plugins, customization, url-rewriting

I'm currently developing a more complex plugin for WP which can't be hooked up to the WP-API itself (Custom Post Types doesn't fit my requirements). Of course I use the API alot, because the data is administered through WP backend (rendering own forms and lists).

I'm stuck with the rewrite options, taxonomities and need just a little hint, how to get the thing working.

What I do have for now is

```
www.example.org/page/?aid=281&kid=104
```

What I'd like to achieve is

```
www.example.org/page/some-name/
```

The vars are already stored in query_vars so far.

Should I try to register a rewrite rule (because 'page' is rendered through WP) and get the things going or should I simply modify the .htaccess?

Any help is much apreciated!